# Can the Oracle JDBC thin driver use a sqlnet.ora file for configuration?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

Can the Type 4 [Oracle JDBC Thin client-side driver](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html#05_04) use a sqlnet.ora file for configuration?

Context: our DBA opend a ticket with Oracle support based on an issue I'm seeing, and their action plan is for me to try adding configuration to a sqlnet.ora file.  They seem to be incorrectly assuming I'm using the OCI driver (I've never worked on an app that used that).  My gut feel is that sqlnet.ora is exclusive to the thick/OCI driver, but my searches aren't turning up a clear answer to that question.

Comment: You are correct: sqlnet.ora is exclusive to the JDBC thick/OCI driver. Changing parameters in sqlnet.ora will have no effect on the JDBC thin connection.

Comment: What setting do you need to add? Although the syntax for the tnsnames.ora entries is different than the syntax for URLs, there might be an equivalent value for the setting. For example, `(SERVER=POOLED)` in a TNS entry would be `:POOLED` in a URL.

Comment: Thanks, but we have a ticket opened with Oracle, so we're going to clarify we're using the thin driver, and then I'm going to let them figure it out for me.  Personally, I think they're on the wrong track and we're sort of at a "is it plugged in" step in their troubleshooting procedures.

Comment: You can use the full Oracle Net connection descriptor (as stored in tnsnames) as a "database specifier" in the connection string for the thin driver. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-6F729E4D-064B-4FD9-AE92-1BD44B8BE5EF__BEICDECB

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin
```

But...

tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora may contain various options. Some of them are implemented by JDBC drivers. Some of them are silently ignored. There is no public information about this.
sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora have a dedicated section in Oracle's documentation and it is not mentioned anywhere whether the same applies also to JDBC drivers.
There are couple of separate notes on Metalink, describing JDBC behavior(bugs), but generally this this topic is not covered anywhere in Oracle's docs.

Check with your DBAs what actually they want to change, and check whether the same feature is also supported by JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

19c JDBC driver allows TNS_ADMIN to be passed as part of the connection URL.
Example., "jdbc:oracle:thin:@wallet_dbname?TNS_ADMIN=/Users/test/wallet_dbname"

Also, Other connection properties can also be passed as part of the connection URL. Refer to [JDBC dev guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-843F6EC2-EDFD-4A88-98DE-B45E1CEADC0E) for more details.